# Accessing DOM element via nativeElement property of ElementRef is a bad practice in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm not talking about manipulating DOM element directly like,
`this.el.nativeElement.value = someText`

I'm trying to code in reactive way so even when it comes to binding events, I was thinking, getting the specific element via `@Viewchild` and bind event on it like, `fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'click')`. This approach works perfectly fine but I notice accessing nativeElement in Angular is considered as a bad practice and should be avoided.

So should I stick to `(click)="onClick()"`? Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If there's a way to do something without nativeElement I'd definitely call it bad practice to use nativeElement anyway. And why would you want to?

On the other hand, there are some things, like canvas graphics, that can't be done without a nativeElement. I wouldn't be so afraid of using nativeElement that I'd jump through hoops or give up capabilities just to avoid it.

Comment: As I stated above, I'm interested in coding in a reactive way, which makes me wonder if accessing `nativeElement` and binding events by using `fromEvent` operator is considered bad. Of course, it's not necessary but if it's not a bad practice, I would definitely want to go with the approach other than `(event)="eventHandler()"`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Renderer 2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)** for this kind of manipulation : it has been made for that purpose.

Comment: As I stated above, I'm not talking about manipulation. I would simply go with `Renderer2` if I were. I'm just talking about accessing the nativeElement.

Comment: Sorry, the implicit answer is **yes**, using nativeElement is a bad practice.

Comment: If you want to bind events to an element, stick to the Angular way. If you need it to be dynamically done, use `NgZone`.